# How to solve cURL error 6: Could not resolve host with Guzzle?

Tags: php, curl, guzzle

Getting this error message when trying to send any request using Guzzle php library. It is HTTP client based on curl. My example code to work:

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_uri' => 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/']);
$response = $client->request('POST', 'access_token');
```

> error: cURL error 6: Could not resolve host: foo.ru (see
>   http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

I have tried any other url, update my `/etc/resolv.conf` error is the same.
Could you give me some ideas how to fix it ?

Ubuntu, PHP 7.2

Comment: Is `foo.ru` a placeholder for a host or is that the actual error message you get?

Comment: It is a placeholder.